# How to get webform field value in hook_webform_results_access

Tags: hooks, webforms

In webform 7.x-4.11 I use this :

```
if (webform_results_access($node)) {
    $actions['resend_app'] = array(
      'title' => t('Resend Appointment'),
      'href' => 'ical/' ,
    );
  }
```

I use it to add a "Resend Appointment" option (just as "resend email") when editing a webform.

I would like to add in the "href" some field value of this webform. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

$submission->data[$sid][0]

for exemple:

```
if (webform_results_access($node) && ($node->nid == '23')) {
      $actions['resend_ical'] = array(
      'title' => t('Resend ical'),
      'href' => 'ical?' . $submission->data[5][0] . '&' . $submission->data[6][0] . '&' . $submission->data[35][0] . '&' . $submission->data[36][0] . '&' . $submission->data[24][0] . '&' . $submission->data[34][0] . '&' . 'node/' . $node->nid . '/submission/' . $submission->sid ,
      'query' => drupal_get_destination(),
    );
  }
```

this is that simple!